# How to use Hook inside Nextjs middleware?

Tags: graphql, next.js

I have a middleware like this

```
import type { NextFetchEvent, NextRequest } from "next/server";
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
import { useCheckIsAdminQuery } from "../../generated/graphql";

export function middleware(req: NextRequest, ev: NextFetchEvent) {
    
    const {data,loading,error} = useCheckIsAdminQuery()
    if(data?.checkIsAdmin){
        return NextResponse.next()
    }else{
        const url = req.nextUrl.clone()
        url.pathname = '/404'
        return NextResponse.redirect(url)
    }

    
}
```

useCheckIsQuery() just a hook was generated by codegen package, but I cannot call this hook inside middleware.
The error display

```
Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.
```

How can i fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to React docs: "`Don't call Hooks inside loops, conditions, or nested functions. Instead, always use Hooks at the top level of your React function, before any early returns.`".

Nextjs' middleware is not a React function, so you cannot use hooks inside it. The solution to your problem is to create a hook with your custom logic, and manually calling it in the page you'd like to take effect.

Comment: Hi @Enfield li. there is any way to handle it? Because my project have a large of pages.

Comment: I think with graphql, the only way to go about this is a custom hook. Take a look at this comment from reddit: https://www.reddit.com/r/nextjs/comments/rfjms6/comment/hoeb0ig/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3

Comment: i read it but it seem not help so much.But i just think about two solutions.

Comment: one is create a Restful API and two is use getServerSideProps. do you think it possible?

Comment: Sorry, my knowlege does not go further than that :)